# Range Slider - JavaScript not running - Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created this range slider inside of CodePen [My Code](https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/GmKxoW). I wanted to save the code in Atom for later use locally, but anytime i try to run the program i get a console error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

I'm new to JS/Jquery. Could someone take a look at my code and let me know why it would run in codepen, but not locally from my computer?

https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/GmKxoW

```js
var sizeRange = ["11x17 - Starting Price <span>- $19.99</span>", // Store string inside of an Array

       "24x36 - Starting Price <span>- $29.99</span>",

       "70x90 - Starting Price <span>- $39.99</span>",

       "120x50 - Starting Price <span>- $49.99</span>",

       "67x18 - Starting Price <span>- $59.99</span>",

       "19x30 - Starting Price <span>- $69.99</span>"]


var imageUrl = new Array(); // Store images inside of an Array

       imageUrl[0] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1Ak.svg';

       imageUrl[1] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1AQ.svg';

       imageUrl[2] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1Bb.svg';

       imageUrl[3] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1Am.svg';

       imageUrl[4] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1CG.svg';

       imageUrl[5] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1By.svg';


$('#sliderPrice').html( sizeRange[0] );

$(document).on('input change', '#range-slider', function() { //Listen to slider changes (input changes)
   var v=$(this).val(); //Create a Variable (v), and store the value of the input change (Ex. Image 2 [imageURL])

  $('#sliderStatus').html( $(this).val() );
  $('#sliderPrice').html( sizeRange[v] );

 $("#img").prop("src", imageUrl[v]); // Modify the Images attribute src based on the sliders value, and input the value inside the imageURL[v] to display image
});

// ::::: Range Slider Thumb ::::: //

$("#range-slider").on("mousedown", function() { //1. When user clicks their mouse down on the Range-Slider
   $(this).removeClass().addClass("thumb-down");//1.1 Remove default class from CSS, and add the class .thumb-down (changes background color)
   $(this).addClass("hover-ring");//1.2 Remove default class from CSS, and add the class .hover-ring (changes box-shadow to a green color)
});

$("#range-slider").on("mouseup", function() { //2. When user mouse-up on Range-Slider

   $(this).addClass("thumb-up"); //2.1 Changes thumb color back to light green

   $(this).addClass("hover-ring-out"); //2.2 Removes Box-Shadow
});

alert("Range Slider Script is loading");
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

.product-range-wrapper {
  displat: -webkit-flex;
  displat:flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction:column;
  max-width:600px;
  margin:0px auto;
  /*outline: 1px solid purple;*/
 }
.product-range-block {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  /*outline: 1px solid red;*/
}
.ref-height-block {
  flex-grow:3;
  /*background-color:red;*/
}
.size-chart-block {
  flex-grow:9;
  /*background-color:green;*/
}
.product-range-block img {
  width:90%;
  /*outline: 1px solid blue;*/
}
#img {
  width: 100% !important;
}


/* ::::::::::::::::::::Range Slider Styles::::::::::::::::::::::::: */
.range-slider-block {
  margin:0px auto;
  width:90%;
  }
#range-slider {
  padding:40px 0px;
  width:100%;
  /*outline: 1px solid green;*/
}
/* Remove Range Sliders Default Styles*/
input[type=range]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
/* Track */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 10px;
    background: #d7d7d7;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
/* Thumb */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #46947F;
    margin-top: -9px;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}
input[type=range]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10pt rgba(190,190,190,0.4);
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* JS Styles */
/* Changes Thumb color to darker green when mousedownn */
input[type=range].thumb-down::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background:#316557;
}
/* Changes Thumb color back to light green when mouseup */
input[type=range].thumb-up::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background:#46947F;
}
/* Changes Ring color Green */
input[type=range].hover-ring::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 6pt rgba(70,148,127,0.46);
    cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=range].hover-ring-out::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0pt rgba(0,0,0,0);
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* Input Value Styles */
#slider_count {
  margin:0px auto;
  width:100%;
  padding:0px 20px;
  text-align:center;
}
#sliderPrice {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size:22px;
  font-weight:600;
}
#sliderPrice span {
  font-weight:600;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Banner Range Slider</title>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="range-slider-ref.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  



<div class="product-range-wrapper">

  <div class="product-range-block">
    <div class="ref-height-block">
      <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/1Ba.svg" alt="Product Height Refrence" height="" width="">
    </div>
    <div class="size-chart-block">
      <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/1Ak.svg" style='' id='img'/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="slider_count"><span id="sliderPrice">0</span></div>
  <div class="range-slider-block">
    <input type="range" id="range-slider" value="0.0" min="0" max="5" step="1" />
  </div>


</div>

<div id="slider_count">Slider Value = <span id="sliderStatus">0</span></div>
<br/>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the range slider is working in codepen. Which you have attached with.

Comment: It's because in your codepen you're including jQuery (What the `$` is), make sure you're including the reference to jQuery locally

Comment: You can see in my HTML document that i have <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

Is this referencing the Jquery correctly?

Comment: I fixed it. I had the wrong CDN link. I replaced it with...

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>